# I want to change the http header User-Agent in Java Swagger. Please help me

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am a new beginner in this field.
I'm currently using the spring boot framework.
My plan is that serving API docs using the Swagger.

But one problem has arisen.

[image: swagger-Ui]

I want to customize the User-Agent like above, but the User-Agent in the picture here doesn't send information.

Perhaps Chrome's User-Agent information is being sent.

Is there a way to change the User-Agent to the information sent from Swagger?

[image: Java code]

Comment: What browser do you use? Chrome [does not allow sending a custom `User-Agent` header](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571722). It should work in Firefox though.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this - [How can I set the user-agent in the http header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925733/how-can-i-set-the-user-agent-in-the-http-header)

Also it looks like your problem statement could be solved using a custom header.